# When does a fetch promise resolve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

Let's say you fetch an image like so:

```
let promise = fetch("http://example.com/example.gif")

promise
.then(async res => {
 // When does code here run?
 // Has the entire image been transferred already upon resolve?
})
```

Is it correct to say that none of the image-file has been sent yet at the moment our fetch-promise resolves? Does a call to `await res.blob()` send some type of communication to the remote server to stream the file over?

Long time fetcher, but want to understand the nuance of how it abstracts HTTP.

Comment: What does the network request look like if you never call `await res.blob()`?

Comment: You need two `await`s. `fetch()` resolves when you first receive headers and then another `json()` or `text()` after the entire request is finished. No guarantee that none of the file has been transferred when fetch resolves. However, calling await does not trigger the rest of the request to download the response, that's happening whether you ask/await for it or not. Having said all that, what's the problem you're actually facing?

Comment: The docs are a good resource: [Response.blob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/blob) and more general [Readable Streams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams) or to start from the beginning [Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API#concepts_and_usage)

Comment: @RuanMendes - awaits? there's nothing in the code about async/await

Comment: @JaromandaX "Does a call to `await res.blob()` send some type of communication to the remote server to stream the file over"

Comment: oops, sorry, only looked at code @RuanMendes :p now the **question** makes less sense :p

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. My question is about the under the hood functionality. I have no issues with async or promise usage of fetch and it's readable stream handlers (blob/json/text/etc). The explanation that fetch resolves after the header has been received is useful info and answers part of my question.

Comment: @LlamaD'Attore The main point is that once you call fetch, the HTTP request/response are going to be executed unless you abort the request. You can be notified that the headers are available from `fetch.then()` and you can read the stream from `res.blob()` I'm not sure which part of your question is not answered.

Comment: Does the readable stream returned by `fetch.then()` get data that's already been transferred into local memory or does it stream it directly from the remote host?

Answer (score 0):

The [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object [`body` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/body) returned by the `fetch()` method is a [ReadableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream), an interface of the [Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API).

> The Streams API allows JavaScript to programmatically access streams of data received over the network and process them as desired by the developer.

So the amount of body data (the image, in this case) received depends on the situation (e.g., server, client internet speed, etc.). If something's holding the stream up on the server side, none of the image file may be sent upon the `fetch()` promise resolving. But if everything's speedy, it might already be done.